# Add buttons in Border Layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jbutton

I would like to add buttons in Border Layout one after another . But I do not know how . 
Thats a part of my code :

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
jp.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
jp2.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
JPanel jp3 = new JPanel();
jp3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

add(jp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
add(jp2, BorderLayout.EAST);
add(jp3, BorderLayout.WEST);

jp.add(btn, BorderLayout.WEST);
jp.add(btn2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
jp.add(btn3, BorderLayout.EAST);

jp2.add(btn4, BorderLayout.NORTH);
jp2.add(btn5, BorderLayout.NORTH);
jp2.add(btn6, BorderLayout.CENTER);
jp2.add(btn7, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
jp2.add(btn8, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

But it add buttons side by side . I am beginner programmer and I really do not idea how to do it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BorderLayout is not suited for what you want - it supports only one component for each constraint (NORTH, SOUTH...)

Use another layout, there are a lot of options, like Gridlayout, GridBagLayout.

I would use TableLayout, it's a very flexible layout - see the homepage address below.
www.clearthought.info/sun/products/jfc/tsc/articles/tablelayout/

Answer (score 1):

JPanel initially has FlowLayout, which places components side by side. Instead of `new JPanel()`, use `new JPanel(new BorderLayout())`

Comment: Also, `BorderLayout` replaces components instead of adding multiples.

Comment: Exactly,as @afk5min mentioned, your bttn4 and bttn7 will be replaced by bttn5 and bttn8 resp.

Comment: Yes , two buttons was disappeared